# Probability In Playing Card Questions

Tags: probability, card-games

Find the probability that a **specific player** gets *4 kings* and **another specific player** gets exactly *2 Aces* in a hand at whist, given that there are *4 players* and *52 playing cards*.

Here's what i did:

> The first specific player gets 4 kings out of 4kings from the deck by 4C4 and the rest 9 cards out of the remaining 44 (=52-4kings-4aces) by 44C9. So probability becomes

```
                           p1 = (4C4)*(44C9)/(52C13)
```

> now to the other player, i gave 2 aces from the 4 available by 4C2 and the remaining 11 cards by 37C11. So, probability becomes

```
                           p2 = (4C2)*(37C11)/(39C13)
```

> Hence, final probability becomes

```
                            p1*p2 = 7.050960*10^(-4)
```

> which is incorrect. **Where did i go wrong?**

Comment: If you are going to take the thirteen cards that you gave player $1$ out of circulation, you need to specify how many aces you thereby removed.  For some reason you appear to assert that player $1$ got no aces at all, but that is not indicated.

Comment: i actually subtracted 4 aces so that i donot have to give any ace to player 1

Comment: Who said player $1$ got no aces?

Comment: i didnt say player 1 will not get any ace.. i just said that he wont get ace when we give the remaining 9 cards to him .. otherwise player 2 may not have 4 available aces for him. after we give 2 aces from the 4 available ones, then it is sure that the remaining two aces might go to player 1 or player 2

Comment: But that means player $1$ was dealt no aces, which was never part of the assumption.  Player $1$ could have $0,1$ or $2$ aces.

Comment: so what do you suggest mate? Should i start with player 2 instead?

Comment: Just go case by case, according to how many aces player $1$ has.  You've already handled the case when player $1$ got $0$ aces (Note:  that value seems low to me, and I did not check your arithmetic).

Comment: Actually, your arithmetic isn't correct.  That expression you wrote is a lot bigger than the value you got.  But it's not the right expression.  Since player $2$ is meant to have exactly $2$ aces and player $1$ got $0$ aces, you should not be taking the $11$ cards from a total of $37$.

Comment: my arithmetic is correct.. but i will go case by case as per your suggestion... If you can help by writing a detailed answer( without doing the arithmetic), it would be highly appreciated... Thanks!

Comment: My bigger point was that the expression for $p_2$ is incorrect.  You should have $\binom {35}{11}$ in the numerator.

Comment: ok ... but is 35 the only correction

Comment: For this case, yes.  You are still incorrectly assuming that player $1$ got $0$ aces.